# iexfinance.utils.exceptions.ImmediateDeprecationError: get_available_symbols has been immediately deprecated. What's it been replaced by?

Tags: python-3.x, api, deprecated

iexfinance.utils.exceptions.ImmediateDeprecationError: get_available_symbols has been immediately deprecated.

Going over some python 3.7 code and after updating some modules getting a few errors, can't seem to find the replacement for get_available_symbols from iexfinance.

I apologise for tags, can't create exact ones.

Answer (score 1):

Answer, for anyone who wants to know:

```
iexfinance.get_available_symbols(**kwargs)
```

MOVED to

```
iexfinance.refdata.get_symbols
```